# Entropy vs energy graphs

Tags: thermodynamics

How to interpret temperature from entropy vs energy graphs?..
And what do the different behaviour of the graph signify and how should I interpret them?(provided volume of the system and number of particles are kept constant)

Comment: $T = \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$. As for how to interpret the graph more generally, you will need to provide more context, as energy is not a simple function of entropy, but also depends on other factors (such as volume).

Comment: Let's say volume and number of particles in the system are constant

Comment: Also what u wrote mathematically came out as a string of characters ..so can u send as an answer maybe?

Comment: What are "the different graphs"?

Comment: Different cases...like concave upwards,concave downwards,a straight line

Comment: First, if you want users to see your comment you need to tag them. Like @SchwarzKugelblitz. Second, the different graphs needs to be clarified in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (or in any good text book), the temperature is given by
$$\frac1T=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}$$
where $T$ is the temperature, $S$ is the entropy, $U$ is the internal energy, $V$ is the volume, and $N$ is the number of particles.

You stated the graphs already assume constant $V$ and $N$, so all you need to do is look at the slope of your graph. The slope determines the temperature.

This is all you need to interpret your "different graphs".